# How to transpose ChordSymbols along with notes in Music21?

Tags: python, music21

I'm trying to transpose a jazz lead sheet. When I transpose the Music21 stream, only the notes are being transposed. The ChordSymbols stay the same.

Here's an example in tinynotation of what I'm seeing. Note: I'm not using TinyNotation in my actual use-case, but it works for providing an example here.

```
from music21 import *

class HarmonyModifier(tinyNotation.Modifier):
    def postParse(self, n):
        cs = harmony.ChordSymbol(n.pitch.name + self.modifierData)
        self.parent().stream.append(cs)
        return n

tnc = tinyNotation.Converter()
tnc.modifierUnderscore = HarmonyModifier
tnc.load("4/4 d2_m7 g4_7 c_maj7")

s = tnc.parse().stream
s.show("text")
s.transpose(interval.GenericInterval(2), inPlace=True)
s.show("text")
```

And here's the output.

```
{0.0} <music21.stream.Measure 1 offset=0.0>
    {0.0} <music21.clef.BassClef>
    {0.0} <music21.meter.TimeSignature 4/4>
    {0.0} <music21.harmony.ChordSymbol Dm7>
    {0.0} <music21.note.Note D>
    {2.0} <music21.harmony.ChordSymbol G7>
    {2.0} <music21.note.Note G>
    {3.0} <music21.harmony.ChordSymbol Cmaj7>
    {3.0} <music21.note.Note C>
    {4.0} <music21.bar.Barline style=final>
# Note ChordSymbols are not changed after transpose()
{0.0} <music21.stream.Measure 1 offset=0.0>
    {0.0} <music21.clef.BassClef>
    {0.0} <music21.meter.TimeSignature 4/4>
    {0.0} <music21.harmony.ChordSymbol Dm7>
    {0.0} <music21.note.Note E>
    {2.0} <music21.harmony.ChordSymbol G7>
    {2.0} <music21.note.Note A>
    {3.0} <music21.harmony.ChordSymbol Cmaj7>
    {3.0} <music21.note.Note D>
    {4.0} <music21.bar.Barline style=final>
```

I'm using music21-4.1.0.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have that facility built in yet. :-(